# Unable to use query with Redis Object Mapper (ROM)

Tags: python, redis

I am using Redis Object Mapper(ROM) [here](http://pythonhosted.org/rom/).

This is my model

`class User(rom.Model):
    name = rom.String(required=True, unique=True)
    nickname = rom.String(required=False)
    photo = rom.String(required=False)`

I am trying -

`user1 = User(name="Ankush", nickname="iamkhush", 
            photo='http://graph.facebook.com/iamkhush/picture')
user1.save()`

I get the result when I do

`user = User.get(1) #user is a model instance`

But when I do

`user_obj = User.query.filter(name='Ankush').execute()`

I get [ ] (An empty result)

Cant get why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two parts to this. First, you *don't* need to use the index if you want to get an item by a column defined with `unique=True`, but the query is different. Using `unique=True` and `index=False`, you can get the item by using the `User.get_by()` form:

```
>>> User.get_by(name="Ankush")
<__main__.User object at 0x87070cc>
```

The primary limitation being that you must pass the full column *exactly* as it is defined in the column. This is generally useful for keeping unique email addresses (lowercase them first!), usernames (be careful with your capitalization), and other examples.

The second part is that when enabling the index, the index has "case-insensitive unique bag-of-words" semantics for string/text columns (I come from the search engine side of the world, which has substantially different (and arguably better) semantics than typical db queries). So if you want to find entries, you need to use:

```
>>> class User(rom.Model):
...     name = rom.String(required=True, unique=True, index=True)
...     nickname = rom.String(required=False)
...     photo = rom.String(required=False)
... 
>>> user1 = User(name="Ankush", nickname="iamankush", photo="http://graph.facebook.com/iamkhush/picture")
>>> user1.save()
>>> User.query.filter(name="ankush").all()
[<__main__.User object at 0x870738c>]
```

(also note that `.execute()` is an alias for `.all()` ).

If you want to change the case-sensitivity or other behavior with columns defined with `index=True`, you need to pass a custom keygen argument (you can see `rom.util._string_keygen()` at https://github.com/josiahcarlson/rom/blob/master/rom/util.py#L149 for `rom.String` and `rom.Text` key generation semantics).

Comment: Make sure your string arguments are lowercased. 

```#Don't do this
User.query.filter(name='Brian').all()
#Do this
User.query.filter(name='brian').all()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass index=True along with name to allow it to be queried by filter.

```
class User(rom.Model):
name = rom.Text(required=True, unique=True,index = True,keygen=text_keyge)
nickname = rom.String(required=False)
photo = rom.String(required=False)
```

Comment: I tried this as well. It doesnt work. I still get an empty list .

Comment: You need to provide keygen argument in this case : name = rom.String(required=True, unique=True, index = True, keygen=text_keyge) and then check if it works

Comment: Or try : name = rom.Text(required=True, unique=True, index = True, keygen=text_keygen)

Comment: What should I give the value of the keygen argument? There is no text_keygen in rom.